# Register using PHP isn't working

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

Trying to simply register, although file is named as Login.html/.php
My HTML form in Login.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register/ Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assets/bootstrap.css"> 
<script src="Assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form action="Login.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Register:</legend>
            Username : <input type="text" name="Username"> <br>
            Password : <input type="password" name="Password"> <br>
            <input type="submit"><br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Have set up the MySQL side of the code and run it as well, it works fine.
The PHP file, Login.php :

```
<?php

    $userErr = $passErr = "";
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "testdb";


    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed");

    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];

    echo("Reached 1. <br>");

    $stmt = "INSERT INTO Login (Username, Password) VALUES ('$Username', '$Password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);

    if($result) {
        echo("Registered Successfully!");
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

When I enter the details and submit, the code for Login.php is displayed,  with the url being: (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Login.php)

Also, Login.html was run on localhost, i.e., url being:
(http://localhost/Login.html)

Comment: Can you run php on local host?

Comment: if you get the php code, then your php install is hooped somehow. which is probably a good thing, since your code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And note that you can **NOT** post to a `file://` url. post/get require an HTTP server, meaning you have to load the page via `http://`

Comment: is php installed/enabled on the localhost webserver ?

Comment: Login systems are **very hard** to get right when it comes to security. If you are doing this to sharpen your skills that's one thing, but honestly if this for a production environment: PLEASE, for the sake of your users, use a 3rd party library with a good reputation.

Comment: You should be [hashing your passwords](http://php.net/password_hash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can guess you are browsing your Login.html with

file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Login.html

But you have to use like this

http://localhost/Login.html